# when save a sublist as variable then append to variable, why is main list affected

Tags: python-3.x, list, variables, append

okay so, in this code, the variable "attractions for destination" is created in the function add_attraction(). this variable saves the sublist of a list (called attractions) as itself. why then, when I come to append to this saved sublist, does it also append to the parent list (attractions). this can be seen when you print() attractions when the function is called and the list seems to be updated, even though the variable appended to was the "attractions_for_destination" variable. does creating a sublist of a list and appending to it individually always reflect onto the main list? here

```
destinations = ["Paris, France", "Shanghai, China", "Los Angeles, USA", "Sao Paulo, Brazil", "Cairo, Egypt"]

test_traveler = ['Erin Wilkes', 'Shanghai, China', ['historical site', 'art']]

def get_destination_index(destination):
  destination_index = destinations.index(destination)
  return destination_index

def get_traveler_location(traveler):
  traveler_destination = traveler[1]
  traveler_destination_index = get_destination_index(traveler_destination)
  return traveler_destination_index

attractions = [[] for place in destinations]

def add_attraction(destination, attraction):
  destination_index = get_destination_index(destination)
  attractions_for_destination = attractions[destination_index]
  attractions_for_destination.append(attraction)


add_attraction("Los Angeles, USA", ['Venice Beach', ['beach']])
print(attractions)
```

the result of this would be:

[[], [], [['Venice Beach', ['beach']]], [], []]

why?

Comment: what is the expected result

Comment: no i was just curious to understand

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the behaviour you see here is to do with how non-trivial objects are handled in python. A list in python does not have a fixed size, meaning that copying it a lot could cause large slowdowns. The solution to this is that instead of copying the list everywhere, references are stored in place and given out to variables that access it. The side effect of this is that if you modify the value of your variable, which is a list stored inside the main list, you are changing the value pointed to by the reference inside the main list. This is why any changes to variables taken from this list reflect back in the original list as well.

If you would like to instead copy a list, you can look at the `copy` module or do a list comprehension like `newlist = [item for item in oldlist]`

Please leave a comment if you have any questions.

Comment: bro amazing reply props to you 